# How to convert NSDictonary from Swift to Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsdictionary

I am following a Tutorial for making a chat application and its written in swift but I am doing it in objective-c, I was not able to figure out how to solve this problem.

I searched for a solution and found nothing because I don't know how to deal with NSDictionary a lot.

The idea is when I receive the request from FIRDatabase there is 4 values in it (fromID, toID, text and timestamp) ID's are referred to users and I need to group the messages (text) for each user in the same key. Here is the Swift code for it.

viewController.swift

```swift
var messages = [Message]()
    var messagesDictionary = [String: Message]()

    func observeMessages() {
        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().refrence().child("messages")
        ref.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let message = Message()
            message.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(dictionary)
            self.message.append(message)

            self.messagesDictionary[message.toID] = message

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
    }, withCancelBlock: nil)

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return messages.count
    }
```

Message.swift

```swift
import UIKit

class Message: NSObject {

    var fromID: String?
    var text: String?
    var timestamp: NSNumber?
    var toID: String?

}
```

This is my Objective-C Code I have right now.

***HomeViewController.m***

```
#import "HomeViewController.h"
#import "messages.h"

@import Firebase;

@interface HomeViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) FIRAuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle handle;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray<messages*> *Messages;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary<NSString*, messages*> *messagesDictionary;
@end

@implementation HomeViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.ref = [[FIRDatabase database] referenceFromURL:@"*****"];

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;

    _Messages = [NSMutableArray<messages*> new];
    _messagesDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary<NSString*, messages*> new];

    [self observeMessages];
}

- (void) observeMessages {

    self.ref = [[[FIRDatabase database] reference] child:@"messages"];
    [_ref observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

        NSString *text = [snapshot.value objectForKey:@"Text"];
        NSString *fromID = [snapshot.value objectForKey:@"fromID"];
        NSString *toID = [snapshot.value objectForKey:@"toID"];
        NSString *timestampString = [snapshot.value objectForKey:@"timestamp"];
        //NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
        //NSNumber *timestamp = [formatter numberFromString:timestampString];

        messages *message = [[messages alloc] initWithFromID:fromID andToID:toID andText:text andTimestamp:timestampString];
        [self->_Messages addObject:message];
        self->_messagesDictionary[message.toID] = message;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self->_tableView reloadData];
        });
}

- (nonnull UITableViewCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];

    self.ref = [[[[FIRDatabase database] reference]child:@"users"]child:[arrayToID objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [_ref observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

        cell.displayName.text = [snapshot.value objectForKey:@"DisplayName"];
    } withCancelBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        //
    }];

    cell.mainLabel.text = [_Messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    //return arrayText.count;
    return _Messages.count;
}
```

***messages.h***

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface messages : NSObject

@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *text;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *fromID;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *toID;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *timestamp;

- (instancetype)initWithFromID:(NSString *)fromID
                  andToID:(NSString *)toID
                   andText:(NSString *)text
                    andTimestamp:(NSString *)timestamp
                     NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;

@end
```

***messages.m***

```
- (instancetype)init {
    return [self initWithFromID:@"" andToID:@"" andText:@"" andTimestamp:@""];
}

- (instancetype)initWithFromID:(NSString *)fromID
                  andToID:(NSString *)toID
                   andText:(NSString *)text
                    andTimestamp:(NSString *)timestamp
                      {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.fromID = fromID;
        self.toID = toID;
        self.text = text;
        self.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Please add Objective-C code that you have.

Comment: @RomanPodymov I did

Comment: And how did you declare `messages` and `messagesDictionary`?

Comment: @RomanPodymov I didn't because I don't know how to do it :) what I need is to convert the swift code to objective-c and to replace my code,, and I don't know if my setup for messages is correct for the job or not

Comment: Check my answer, I think I understand your problem now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add new properties `NSArray<Message*>* messages` and `NSMutableDictionary<NSString*, Message*>* messagesDictionary` to the class where you declared `- (void)observeMessages`. You will get something like that:

```
@interface MyClass: NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray<Message*>* messages;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary<NSString*, Message*>* messagesDictionary;

- (void)observeMessages;

@end
```

Then initialise these properties:

```
_messages = [NSArray<Message*> new];
_messagesDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary<NSString*, Message*> new];
```

Remove these lines (I guess you also don't know why did you add them):

```
[self->arrayText addObject:text];
[self->arrayFromID addObject:fromID];
[self->arrayToID addObject:toID];
[self->arrayTimestamp addObject:timestampString];
```

Use this code to add a new `Message` instance both to `messages` and `messagesDictionary`:

```
Message* message = [[Message alloc] initWithFromID:fromID andToID:toID andText:text andTimestamp:timestampString];
if (message.toID != nil) {
    _messagesDictionary[message.toID] = message;
    _messages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:_messagesDictionary.allValues];
}
```

All code in this post was tested in Xcode 10.2.1.

Comment: Did it all, But when I changed the return count to `return _Messages.count;` in `numberOfRowsInSection` it returned 1 cell ,, originally its 4 with 2 toID the same so it should return 3,, also how can I retrieve the data from it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ? tried `cell.mainLabel.text = [_Messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` but didn't work

Comment: @IQaid What `_Messages` is?

Comment: It's `_messages = [NSMutableArray<Message*> new];` regarding your answer but I changed it to `_Messages` because my NSObject file named **messages.h\.m** so I tweaked it a letter bit to run and this is an example of what I did `self->_Messages = [NSMutableArray<messages*> new];` also changed `self->_messagesDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary<NSString*, messages*> new];` and the rest

Comment: Where do you call `self->_Messages = [NSMutableArray<messages*> new]` and `self->_messagesDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary<NSString*, messages*> new];`?

Comment: inside - (void) observeMessages

Comment: @IQaid If `- (void)observeMessages` is declared in view controller you should initialise them in `viewDidLoad`. What is the superclass of the class where you declared `- (void)observeMessages`?

Comment: Ok I did, it returned 4 cells not 3 as its supposed, these 4 returns have 2 toID the same ,, so it should group it into one so the total return will be 3. please watch this video from min 20 to have a better understanding of what I need https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fyqksNlC8ks

Comment: @IQaid Add more code if you want to solve this problem.

Comment: @IQaid But as I can see you need to call `_messages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: _messagesDictionary.allValues];`, not `[_messages addObject:message];`.

Comment: Great ,, how to get the data to insert it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ?

Comment: @IQaid Do you mean this line `cell.mainLabel.text = [_Messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`?

Comment: @IQaid I think here should be something like `cell.mainLabel.text = [_Messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].text;`.